# How to get newly added branch in my already forked repo?

Tags: git, github, versioning

I've already forked a repo from a main stream and been using my own repo and now the admin added a new branch on the main stream then at that condition how can I get that newly created branch on my fork. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually better to work with the command line. So you have to:

- add the original repo as a remote (the usual name is `upstream`)
- pull the new branch from upstream to your local repo
- push your local repo to your fork on github (the remote is `origin` by default)

This is true for every change that you want to get from the original repository. This is a common workflow.

For example this is an example where you want to get new commits made on upstream/master. The concept it's almost the same with new branches in upstream. The only difference is that in this case you won't need a merge the first time.

[Sync Fork](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/)